# Rearranging $ca^{b-1}/d^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm am try to rearrange $\frac{ca^{b-1}}{d^2}$ to $\large{\frac{c}{d^2a^{b-1}}}$ but I am having difficulty. I have tried times both top and bottom with various expressions such as $a^{b-1}$ but with no luck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking how to rearrange so that
$$ \frac{ca^{b-1}}{d^2}=\frac{c}{d^2a^{b-1}}\,\,?$$
Generally this is not true unless $a=1$. What is true is that 
$$ \frac{ca^{b-1}}{d^2}=\frac{ca^{b-1}a^{1-b}}{d^2a^{1-b}}=\frac{c}{d^2a^{1-b}}$$